# Using JavaFX- Cannot addAll(Text field, Text area, String). Shouldn't I be able to?

Tags: user-interface, methods, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

My code:

```
public class Main extends Application {

TextArea area = new TextArea();
TextField field = new TextField();
String text = "";
public void start(Stage primaryStage){

    VBox pane = new VBox();
    Button next = new Button("Next");
    next.setOnAction(e->{
        text+= "\n" + field.getText();
        area.setText(text);
    });
    pane.getChildren().addAll(area,field,next);
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 700, 300);
    primaryStage.setTitle("CosmicWimpout");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

The error is on the `.addAll`, the error reads:

```
The method addAll(int, Collection<? extends Node>) in the type List<Node> is not applicable for the arguments (TextArea, TextField, String).
```

So I just edited my post to include .addAll(area, field, next). These are all GUI Nodes, yet the.addAll method does not accept these parameters.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen when adding a `String` to a `VBox`? It only accepts `Node`s.

Comment: edited code to use next which is a button node. Still a problem.

Comment: That should work. Could you create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question to include it? This may be an error with wrong import.

Comment: Thats exactly what the problem was! I needed to import javafx.scene.control.*; not java.awt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @sillyfly already pointed out the `pane` is of type `VBox` which is a subtype of `Parent`. The method [`getChildren`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html#getChildren--) will return an `ObservableList` of type `Node`. Therefore the method [`addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html#addAll-E...-) on the children list will take as argument a var-arg of type `Node`. A `String` is clearly not of type `Node`.

Comment: Are there any other possible Panes (other than VBox) that allow for adding these objects?

Comment: All panes are of type `Parent`. Maybe you can use a `Text` or `Label` Node instead of the `String`.

Comment: I edited my code, that string parameter was not supposed to be there, but rather the next parameter (which is a button) was supposed to be there. So they are all nodes.

Answer (score 1):

What classes are you importing? For me the error occured when I imported:

```
import java.awt.Label;
```

instead of:

```
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
```

This often occurs when your IDE is importing the classes automatically for you. Sometimes you should consider entering them manually.